# Recyclerview native Ads Refresh issue android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, google-native-ads

i have recyclerview with room database. and this recyclerview contains Native ads on very 4th position. the problem is when i observe the room data recyclerview automatically refresh Ads position.

Hear is my code viewmodel observer code.

```
smsViewModel.getConversation().observe(this@HomeScreenActivity) { conversations ->
        clearSelection()
     
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            for (conversation in conversations) {
                for (resIds in conversation.recipientsIds) {
                    val recipients = ArrayList(smsViewModel.getRecipientById(resIds))
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                        if (recipients.isNotEmpty()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Recipients  if: $resIds  ${recipients.size}")
                            conversation.recipients.addAll(recipients)
                        }else{
                            Log.i(TAG, "Recipients  else: $resIds  ${recipients.size}")
                        }
                        conversationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }

                }
            }
        }


        val conversationList = when (cat) {
            resources.getString(R.string.cat_all) -> {
                    val sortList =
                conversations.sortedWith(compareByDescending<Conversation> { conversation ->
                    conversation.pinned || !conversation.archived
                }.thenByDescending { it.date })
                    .toMutableList()
                 getListWithAds(sortList)
            }

            resources.getString(R.string.cat_personal) -> {
                conversations.filter { conversation ->
                    isMobileNumberWithPlus(conversation.lastMessage!!.address)
                }.sortedByDescending { it.date }
            }

            resources.getString(R.string.cat_transaction) -> {
                getConversationType(conversations, 1)
            }

            resources.getString(R.string.cat_otps) -> {
                getConversationType(conversations, 2)
            }

            resources.getString(R.string.cat_offers) -> {
                getConversationType(conversations, 3)
            }

            resources.getString(R.string.menu_archived) -> {
                val sortList = conversations.filter { it.archived }
                    .sortedWith(compareByDescending<Conversation> { it.archived }
                        .thenByDescending { it.date })
                    .toMutableList()
                getListWithAds(sortList)
            }

            else -> {
                conversations.sortedByDescending { it.date }
            }
        }
        convList.clear()
        convList.addAll(conversationList)
        conversationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        updateVisibility(cat)
    }

}
```

Please give me any solution.

i have tried paging 3 library for that issue.